# Are there any complex solutions to the equation ${x}^{2^x} = {2}^{{x}^{{x}^{2}}}$?

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

Thought of this question after learning about the Lambert W function and wanted to challenge myself. Are there any complex solutions to the equation $${x}^{2^x} = {2}^{{x}^{{x}^{2}}}$$

Tried to work it out but it just kept getting more and more convoluted and disastrous, I suspect the solution will need the Lambert W function, but I don't know how to apply it. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is your equation supposed to be $x^{2^x} = 2^{x^{x^2}}$?

Comment: Yes, thank you, sorry; it's been a while since I used mathjax and I couldn't preview the title to check if it looked correct.

Comment: Okay I edited the title for you.

Comment: It seems that there are several complex roots, here are some approximations: $$-0.8012457755\ldots + 0.2129684866\ldots i$$ $$-0.3007776596\ldots + 
 1.451745119\ldots i$$ $$1.415987123\ldots + 0.3175997103\ldots i$$

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to find the exact values though?

Comment: I really doubt it. Equations that are a lot simpler than this one doesn't have closed form for its solutions.

Comment: $e^z=z$ has roots $z_k$ while $e^{e^z}=z$ has roots $z_{k_1,k_2}$. With “higher” power towers, there are more branches of complex solutions. One possibly finds a series/integral solution, but this question can include more detail on context/ efforts. Also, you can see all complex roots [here](https://samuelj.li/complex-function-plotter/#2%5Ez%5Ez%5E2-z%5E2%5Ez) where the contours are concentric circle-like.

Comment: Makes sense tbh, thanks for the morale boost tho. Used a lot of paper trying to solve it lol. May I ask how you found these approximations?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash my efforts were definitely not worth sharing, but i do see what you mean, thanks

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be infinitely many complex solutions.  Here is a plot of $\text{Re}(x^{2^x} - 2^{x^{x^2}}) = 0$ (red) and
$\text{Im}(x^{2^x} - 2^{x^{x^2}}) = 0$ (blue)
for $1.1 \le \text{Re}(x) \le 2.3$, $-0.6 \le \text{Im}(x) \le 0.6$.  Each intersection of a red and a blue curve corresponds to a solution.  This is just a small part of a complicated picture.

[image]

Comment: It was blocked by my school lol, I'll check it as soon as possible. In the mean time, thank you so much for the graph (i hope).